# How to put an ASP.Net website inside MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have an ASP.Net website and I want to put this website inside a MVC website I recently did, so this ASP.Net website will be part from the MVC website.
Is there a standard or a known way to do so?

Ask me if you want to know more information, I am not sure what info could help.

Answer (score 1):

this shows merging an existing asp.net site into a new MVC3 site. The same applies for merging existing into existing. Just get a merge tool and merge them!
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your MVC project into the webforms one?  If so, this nuget will help with that: http://www.nuget.org/Tags/WebForms